# Disassembling an 'faddl' instruction

Tags: x86, disassembly, opcode, instruction-set, x87

In my venture of coding a disassembler for the 32-bit Linux on x86 platform, I came across an issue. I saw the following opcode sequence when I disassembled a simple ELF-32 executable using `objdump`:

```
dc 82 04 08 0d 00     faddl  0xd0804(%edx)
```

But when I look at the [Intel manual](http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/243191.HTM), I don't see an opcode corresponding to this. The `fadd` instruction starts with 0xDC, but then it requires a `m64fp` operand, which is "A memory quadword operand in memory."

Now, does this mean that the operand is a 64-bit address (which then means that the `fadd` instruction is a 64-bit instruction, but isn't prefixed by a REX byte), or is it just a 32-bit address which points to a quadword (64-bit)?

Am I missing something trivial over here, or is my understanding of encoding x86 instructions wrong?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't looked at SO for quite some time. Will do it now.

Comment: Note that the Intel manuals use Intel notation, whereas linux uses AT&T notation, so you will not be able to look up linux opcodes in the Intel manual directly.

Answer (score 5):

Let's break this down.

```
> dc 82 04 08 0d 00     faddl  0xd0804(%edx)
  |  |  \____ ____/
  |  |       V
  |  |       |
  |  |       +---------> 32-bit displacement
  |  +-----------------> ModRM byte
  +--------------------> Opcode
```

Looking at the docs in detail, `dc` is indeed for an `m64real` floating point argument as the source. It will add this 64-bit argument to the `ST(0)` floating point register.

However, it's the *second* byte `82` that is deciding where that 64-bit value comes from. This translates to the binary ModRM byte of:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  MOD  |  REG/OPCD |    R/M    |
```

If you look at table 2.2 in your linked document (the one for 32-bit addressing modes), you'll see that this translates into `disp32[EDX]`.

In other words it takes the next 32 bits (four bytes), adds that to the `edx` register and uses that address to extract the 64-bit value from memory.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should first study the docs in full detail.

Answer (score 2):

"Quadword operand in memory" means the value takes 64 bits in RAM. The address size will depend on whether it is being compiled as a 32 or 64 bit process, not on how big the operands are. Here is a full breakdown of the disassembly.

- The first byte, `DC` is the opcode. Combined with the fact that the next byte is not between C0 and C7, and contains 0 in the register field (bits 3-5), this indicates a `fadd` instruction with a 64 bit memory operand. Interestingly, the `l` at the end of the opcode would indicate a 32 bit operand. It should be `faddq`.
- The second byte contains 3 fields.

  - Bits 6-7 are indicate the mode of the last field.
  - Bits 3-5 are the register field. Since a register operand isn't necessary for this instruction, they are used as part of the opcode.
  - Bits 0-2 are the R/M field. It can hold a register or specify a memory operand. The combined mode `10` and R/M `010` indicate that the operand is a memory operand with a 32 bit address relative to the `edx` register.
- The last 4 bytes are the relative offset of the operand in little endian (least significant byte first).

Comment: Thanks, I'll first read the docs in detail. I guess I'm trying to jump steps, which ain't working very well.

Comment: Perhaps the `faddl` applies to he 32-bit displacement operand rather than the 64-bit quadword it points to?

Comment: @paxdiablo No, instruction suffixes always refer to operand size. You can tell the size of the displacement by what range it fits in (0xd0804 fits in 32 bits, but not 8), but it isn't explicitly stated because it usually isn't important.